# Raspberry PI Compute Module - SPI1

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, driver, raspbian, spi

I'm using **Raspberry PI Compute Module**, and i would like to use **SPI1**.

But there is a struggle.

Are there any **drivers** or do you have some **idea** how to use that? *Because there are only drivers for SPI0 which is the only SPI accessible in Raspberry PI B+.*

Thank you.

Comment: Which kernel version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't find any kernel suitable. But yes you can using this library which is well writen :
http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html

To use the second SPI, use the example program in x_pigpio.c void tc().
Change the parameters in

```
h = spiOpen(1, 50000, 0);
```

In gpio.h, you can check what to put in the 3 parameters :

```
int spiOpen(unsigned spiChan, unsigned baud, unsigned spiFlags);
```

spiChan: 0-1 (0-2 for A+/B+/Pi2 auxiliary device) baud: 32K-125M (values above 30M are unlikely to work) and spiFlags :

Returns a handle (>=0) if OK, otherwise PI_BAD_SPI_CHANNEL,
PI_BAD_SPI_SPEED, PI_BAD_FLAGS, PI_NO_AUX_SPI, or PI_SPI_OPEN_FAILED.
spiFlags consists of the least significant 22 bits.

. .
21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
 b  b  b  b  b  b  R  T  n  n  n  n  W  A u2 u1 u0 p2 p1 p0  m  m
. .

mm defines the SPI mode.

So now that you understood, you take the example, change the parameters or spiOpen like that and it's working.

```
spiChan = 1
spiFlags = PI_SPI_FLAGS_GET_AUX_SPI(1)
```

The best way to confirm it's working is to make a loop between your MISO and MOSI pins and checking with a logic analyzer your message is readable.